# Array filter with possible undefined properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects that may or not contain a property.

So, in order to filter it, I do this:

```
array = array.filter(v => v.myproperty != undefined);
array = array.filter(v => v.myproperty[0] != undefined);
```

This effectively removes the ones where `myproperty` is undefined and, afterwards, the ones where the first element inside `myproperty`.

Is there a way of having a single liner that prevents me from applying `filter` to the array twice?

Something like:

```
array = array.filter((v => v.myproperty || [])[0] != undefined);
```

Comment: Wouldn't `array = array.filter(v => v.myproperty != undefined && v.myproperty[0] != undefined);` work?

Comment: No, that would error: "myproperty is not defined" as it is trying to access index 0 of something undefined

Comment: But `&&` short-circuits, right? If `myproperty` is undefined, `myproperty[0]` will not be evaluated.

Comment: @Blorgbeard, no, the `filter` tries to check both conditions, and I am getting `myproperty is not defined`

Comment: Sorry @Blorgbeard, in fact, you are right. `&&` short-circuits and the second condition is not evaluated. This behaviour is different from C#, where all the conditions are evaluated, and I had that mindset when looking at this one. Thanks

Comment: No problem. But you might want to double-check C#'s behaviour on this, because it definitely short-circuits `&&` too.

Comment: No, it doesn't @Blorgbeard. [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/z712dt) is an example.

Comment: That example is bad.. `&&` can't short-circuit (in C# or javascript) when the first argument evaluates to true. It doesn't even make sense to say "if something is null AND something.property is null". A better example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/CxJPAw - note no NPE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
filtered_array = array.filter(element => element.property && element.property[0]);
```

What the condition do is to evaluate the left part first. If it's true, it will try to evaluate the right part and return the result.

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/3Lsswos7/).

Answer (score 3):

In the end, `array.filter()` takes an anonymous function that is expecting a boolean result.  You can do any amount of work inside to determine if the array item should be filtered.

```js
var array = [1, 2, undefined, 3, "some text", [5,6,7],[], [undefined,8]]

array = array.filter(v => {

  if (!v) return false;

  if (v === "some text") return false;
  
  if (Array.isArray(v) && v.length === 0) return false;
  
  if (Array.isArray(v) && v[0] === undefined) return false;

  return true;

});


console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do what others have already suggested here, the function will return if the first condition fails.

```
    array => array.filter(v => v.ggwp && v.ggwp[0])
```

You can also use the in operator to accomplish the same thing like this:

```
    array => array.filter(v => ('myproperty' in v) && (0 in v.myproperty))
```

Here's a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fayaneh/edit?js,console) with some testcases that compare these two functions to yours.

I'm not sure though that you want to use `!=` in your code instead of `!==`. Javascript, because of type coercion has [weird behaviour](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Answer (score 2):

> Something like `array.filter((v => v.myproperty || [])[0] != undefined);`

Yes, exactly something like that. You only misplaced one parenthesis:

```
array.filter( v => (v.myproperty || [])[0] != undefined);
//           ^     ^
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have complex boolean logic in your statement.

```
let array = [{num: [1]}, {num: [2]}, {num: [3]}, {num: undefined}, {}]
array = array.filter(v => v && v.num && v.num.length)
```

For readability and testability you may want to break it out into a function that you can test somewhere else.

```
function predicate(v) {
  return v && v.num && v.num.length
}
let array = [{num: [1]}, {num: [2]}, {num: [3]}, {num: undefined}, {}]
array = array.filter(predicate)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should also check if the properties element is an array. Checking for the property only with `element.property[0]` will also be true for strings. Besides that, you can pass anything returning a boolean inside filter, just like you would do in a if statement.

```
arr.filter(e => 'myproperty' in e && 
      Array.isArray(e.myproperty) && 
      e.myproperty[0] !== undefined)
```